# New Cursive deps module - "Clojure jar not attached to this module"

Tags: cursive

In Cursive with a new deps module (within an existing project which uses lein) I'm getting:

"Run configuration error: The Clojure jar is not attached to this module"

How do I attach it?

Relatedly, none of the clojure core functions are recognised by the editor when the file is open (I mean for the editor's code analysis purposes).

But, when I run -main in that new module with `clj` directly from the terminal, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - open Project Structure and look at the bottom of the left panel in the window that opens, below Platform SDKs, there's a discrete entry called "Problems".  If you click that it offers to Fix and adds clojure, spec, etc. as dependencies of the new deps module.